# Link and adjacent text get merged: how to preven that?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

Say I start with:

```
{}{foo}
```

and insert a link inside the first pair of braces:

```
{https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask}{foo}
```

It will link to

```
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask%7D%7Bfoo
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: What about using a space between `}` and `{`?  Or what about using the explicit notation of Org for links by using `[[` and `]]` instead of the curly braces that contain the url?

Comment: `[[url]]` inside braces works.